# Equivalent of PERL Carp->cluck( $msg ) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, perl, stack-trace, perl-module

Perl has a module named Carp, from which one could use to print out messages (w.o explcitly raising an exception), that prints message and a complete stack trace.
I.e.

```
use Carp qw(cluck) ;
cluck ("foo")
```

Would yield:

```
foo called from file bar, line 2
```

Any ideas how to get something similar in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Kernel#caller_locations` for this (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations)

```
def cluck(val)
  loc = caller_locations.last
  puts "#{val} called from file #{loc.path}, line #{loc.lineno}"
end

cluck 1
cluck "hello"
```

Output:

```
1 called from file line_of_caller.rb, line 6
hello called from file line_of_caller.rb, line 7
```

`loc` here is an instance of Thread::Backtrace::Location, so you can also get more info from it; check out http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html